# C++: Determining derived type from a base type pointer

Tags: c++

**Background:**

See [this question in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inversion.html) for a similar situation that I need to solve, but with named constructors.

I have a Base class, `class B`.

I have a Derived class from B, `class D`, **that adds additional functionality via functions, members, and additional memory allocation**.

**The additional functionality is polymorphically supported in `class B` by doing nothing or returning default values and `nullptrs` from the virtual functions specific to `class D`.**

`class B` uses `public static Factory Methods` for construction with all `protected constructors`. (see: [Named Constructor Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-ctor-idiom.html))

`class D` uses `public static Factory Methods` for construction with all `protected constructors` that are named differently from class B and not available in class B.

Sometime later, a new interface class is created, `class A`. This class has an interface such that the derived classes from `class A` must have a getter function and a setter function that both require a `pointer to a class B` but the dynamic value can be either `class B` or `class D`

**Question:**

I want to derive `class A` and create a copy constructor, an assignment operator, and/or a setter for `class B` but because `class A` only exposes its member(s) as an object of type `B` I have no way of determining if the object returned is `class B` or `class D`.

How would I correctly implement the above using only the public interface without causing slicing or memory issues (including if the above is set up wrong and needs to be changed)?

**Possible solutions?:**

I'm tempted to try a couple of options:

1) Create a member in class B and all derived types that declares the type of object:

```
if(getB()->GetType() == "D") {
    //Call D::CreateD(...)
} else if(getB()->GetType() == "B") {
    //Call B::CreateB(...)
}
```

2) Dynamically cast to the derived type and check for failure:

```
if(dynamic_cast<D*>(getB()) == nullptr) {
    //Call B::CreateB(...)
} else {
    //Call D::CreateD(...)
}
```

3) Use a virtual method that is specific to `class D` that I know returns `nullptr` when used on a `class B` object:

```
if(getB()->VirtualMethodSpecificToClassD() == nullptr) {
    //Call B::CreateB(...)
} else {
    //Call D::CreateD(...)
}
```

All three cases have code smells:

1. Causes "else-if-heimers".
2. Not too sure this will actually work.
3. Violates the good practice of "code to interfaces not implementations".

Comment: Have you considered a virtual `B::Copy()`?

Comment: @zneak: did you mean `clone()`?

Comment: @Drakosha: did you mean duplicate() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `zneak`'s comment, I think that if you're using factory methods and private constructors, there's nothing too smelly about having a

```
 virtual B* copy() const { return new B(*this); /* calls private B::B(const B&) */ }
```

method in class `B`, overridden in class `D` (returning a new `D*` -- this usage of covariant return types is specifically permitted in C++).

Then your `A` copy constructor can do something like

```
A::A(const A& other) : b(other.getB()->copy()) {}
```

and it should work okay.

---

On the other hand, if you'd rather go with one of the solutions you've suggested, I think that the first is the least pungent -- although I'd go for an enum rather than a string, so you can use a simple switch statement rather than string compares. I believe LLVM uses something like this for "dynamic casting", to avoid the C++ RTTI overhead.